# measure barometric pressure using boiling water

Tags: pressure, experimental-technique

I have set a cup of water in a bell jar, with a thermometer.  I am able to lower the pressure until the water boils and I am able to measure the temperature of the water simultaneously. I then looked at a phase diagram for water, and found where the temperature axis line intersects the liquid to vapor phase change line.  I then used the Antoine Equation to solve for the pressure at which the water was observed to start boiling.

I have several electronic barometers (which measure in inches of water column) and are showing several inches difference between then.  I am looking for a good way to set them to a known absolute pressure reference.

Is this a good way to determine barometric pressure?  Is it prone to a bunch of esoteric sources of errors?  Is there a method available that I can follow to do this experiment with uncertainties?

Comment: What's the range of pressures you need to measure? "[...] and are showing several inches difference between them". *Inches of what?*

Comment: How are your significant figures? It can throw off your calculation if you round your numbers too early.

Comment: @Gert He says. "(which measure in inches of water column)"

Comment: @CoilKid: ooops! I don't think he's rounding anything, though.

Comment: my absolute pressure range is 0 to 800 inches of water @4°C.  The barometers that I'm fighting with have an accuracy of ±0.3 inches of water, and a resolution of ±0.01 inches of water.  I am boiling water around 9.6 inches of water, with a room temperature of about 20.1°C.

Comment: I also have a gage pressure (vacuum module) with an accuracy of ±0.15 inH2O@4°C, but i do not have a good absolute pressure reference.  So my error is going to be dominated by my inability to measure absolute pressure.  I am hoping to do the experiment described above in lieu of buying a barometer.

Answer (score 0):

To measure absolute pressure, take advantage of the ideal gas law,
$$
PV = NkT.
$$
For an isolated pressure system (constant $N$) you should be able to change the pressure $P$ by a known amount by changing the temperature $T$ or the volume $V$.  You could for instance put your pressure vessel in the freezer for a few hours (265 K or so) then pop it in some water and boil is (373 K or so) for a ~30% pressure change.  You'll need to check in advance whether your barometer is temperature sensitive.